# json file to mysql database a column inserted as "array"

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

Crypto currency names in the JSON file are saved as "array" in the mysql database. How can I add these names to the column named "Adi"? I need coin names to be added to the database as well. It processes all data into my database in one go, but does not get the coin name (such as BTC _TL, ETH_TL)

view of the database (coin names will appear in the red marked); https://ibb.co/17gvJVR

MY JSON CODES;

```
{
"BTC_TL": {
"lowestAsk": 303250,
"highestBid": 302951,
"low24hr": 296000,
"high24hr": 310990,
"avg24hr": 303800.18554769,
"volume": 1230.70390836,
"last": 303249,
"change": -1749,
"percentChange": -0.6,
"chartData": [
  
]
},
"ETH_TL": {
"lowestAsk": 9967,
"highestBid": 9956,
"low24hr": 9070,
"high24hr": 10194,
"avg24hr": 9539.62230136,
"volume": 27905.94836496,
"last": 9956,
"change": 799.21,
"percentChange": 8.7,
"chartData":[ \[][1]
  
]
},
"XRP_TL": {
"lowestAsk": 2.61,
"highestBid": 2.606,
"low24hr": 2.401,
"high24hr": 2.7,
"avg24hr": 2.50030057,
"volume": 35478235.00648834,
"last": 2.606,
"change": 0.192,
"percentChange": 8,
"chartData": [
  
]
},
"BTC_USDT": {
"lowestAsk": 40829.01,
"highestBid": 40828,
"low24hr": 39200,
"high24hr": 41550.55,
"avg24hr": 40540.35763825,
"volume": 4.27793552,
"last": 40828,
"change": 1225,
"percentChange": 3.1,
"chartData": [
  
]
},
```

my php codes;

```
 <?php
      
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
      $query = '';
      $table_data = '';
      $filename = "coin.json";
      $data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
      $array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
      foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
      
      {
       $query .= "INSERT INTO tablename(Adi, lowestAsk, highestBid, low24hr, high24hr, avg24hr, volume, last, `channge`, percentChange)  VALUES('".$array."', '".$row["lowestAsk"]."', '".$row["highestBid"]."', '".$row["low24hr"]."', '".$row["high24hr"]."', '".$row["avg24hr"]."', '".$row["volume"]."', '".$row["last"]."', '".$row["change"]."', '".$row["percentChange"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
       $table_data .= '
        <tr>
   <td>'.$row["low24hr"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["lowestAsk"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["highestBid"].'</td>
  </tr>
       '; //Data for display on Web page
      }
      if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{
 
 echo '<h3>datas</h3><br />';
 echo '
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th width="45%">low24hr</th>
     <th width="10%">lowestAsk</th>
     <th width="45%">highestBid</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
 echo $table_data;  
 echo '</table>';
 
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: Never use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: @dharman Thanks, what should I use instead?

Comment: You need to execute each statement separate as a prepared statement. See my first comment. You can learn more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli